# ReactJS: Navigate from a page to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have created two more page, the first one is an homepage (and I can go in this page) and the second page is a Create form (i can't go here!)

my folder structure:

```
application:
> application.tsx
> application-update.tsx
> index.tsx
// there I have created a new folder (LegacyFolder) with the page 
>LegacyFolder
    >>index.tsx
    >>applicationLegacy.tsx
    >>applicationLegacy-update.tsx
```

I copied (with some changes obviously ) my application/index.tsx in my LegacyFolder/index.tsx

```
import ApplicationLegacy from './applicationLegacy';
import ApplicationLegacyUpdate from './applicationLegacy-update';

const Routes = ({ match }) => (
  console.log('match ', match),
  (
    <>
      <Switch>
        <ErrorBoundaryRoute path={match.url} component={ApplicationLegacy } /> // (I can go there)
        <ErrorBoundaryRoute exact path={`${match.url}/new`} component={ApplicationLegacyUpdate } /> // I can't go there
      </Switch>
    </>
  )
);

export default Routes;
```

Now from my menu I can go in the ApplicationLegacy.

Inside ApplicationLegacy i have a button to go in the ApplicationLegacyUpdate page:

```
<Link to={`${match.url}/new`} className="btn btn-primary jh-create-entity" id="jh-create-entity" data-cy="entityCreateButton">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon="plus" />
          &nbsp; <Trans i18nKey="applicazione.create">{'applicazione.create'}</Trans> Application
        </Link>
```

When I click here my url changes to `/applicationLegacy/new` but the page doesn't change.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could solve the problem if you add prop exact to the first one component called ErrorBoundaryRoute that is responsible for showing component called ApplicationLegacy.

Comment: @Jack23 great :)